# Convergence of double-infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $r\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and $0<\lambda<1$. Prove that double-infinite series
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}k^r\lambda^k$$
is convergent.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but what does $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote? Never saw that subscript before...

Comment: @HasanSaad Typically it represents $\mathbb{N}_0=\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @HasanSaad I believe this refers to the natural numbers together with 0. Numbers like 0,1,2....

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know this notation was used. Sorry for such a trivial question :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Each term $k^r \lambda^k$ appears exactly $(k+1)$ times in the double summation if you expand it into a single summation. So really all you have to show is that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)k^r \lambda^k$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to another answer, lets test convergence with the ratio test. k approaches infinity for reference.
$${{(k+2)(k+1)^r{\lambda}^{k+1}} \over {(k+1)(k)^r{\lambda}^{k}}}$$
$${{(k+2)(k+1)^{r-1}{\lambda}} \over {(k)^r}}$$
$${{(k+2)({{k+1} \over k})^{r}{\lambda}} \over {(k+1)}}$$
$${{(k+2)({1+1/k})^{r}{\lambda}} \over {(k+1)}}$$
The maximum value will be at r approaching infinity. However, this is just the definition of e.
$${{(k+2)e{\lambda}} \over {(k+1)}}$$
$${{(1+2/k)e{\lambda}} \over {(1+1/k)}}$$
$${{(1)e{\lambda}} \over {(1)}}$$
This is larger than one so the series converges for r less than the critical value and diverges for r greater than it.

Comment: Thank you, the trick of summing the series in a different way was a key here. The ratio test is then straightforward. Thanks to both of you!